# Transforming a trigonometric product into a sum.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have this equation: $sin(2x)\cdot\cos(3x)$, and I have to use the relation $sin(a+b) = sin(a)\cdot\cos(b) + sin(b)\cdot\cos(a)$ to turn it into a sum of terms.

So far I have done this:

$sin(3x + 2x) = sin(2x)\cdot\cos(3x) + sin(3x)\cdot\cos(2x)$ and juggling the the terms I get:

$sin(2x)\cdot\cos(3x) = sin(5x) - sin(3x)\cdot\cos(2x)$.

The expect answer for me to give is $\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\big[sin(5x) - sin(x)\big]$, but I can't seem to figure this out.

Deeply appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: See  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trivially you have:
$$
\sin(3x+2x)=\sin(3x)\cos(2x)+\cos(3x)\sin(2x) \\
\sin(3x-2x)=\sin(3x)\cos(2x)-\cos(3x)\sin(2x)
$$

Substracting both equalities follows the results

Comment: Oh my god, thanks. I don't know how I didn't see this yesterday. Next time I'm going to sleep before doing my coursework.